# How to join two tables by matching the date in one table with the date closest to and before in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

[image: Tables and Desired Output Examples]

I am looking for a query to try and get the set of world rankings prior to each event. This is eventually to be used in a linear regression model to see the accuracy of predicting event results with world ranking. NB. there can be multiple tournaments on the same day.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` to get a time period *before* each event.  Then `join`:

```
select e.*, r.*
from rankings r left join
     (select e.*,
             lag(event_date) over (order by event_date) as prev_event_date
      from events e
     ) e
     on r.ranking_date < event_date and
        (r.ranking_date >= prev_event_date or prev_event_date is null)
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this very helpful, sorry I'm pretty new to MySQL. Would you be able to explain what the single letter notation means? As in why do you write "from events e" rather than "from events"

Comment: @hyphen_question . . . Those are table aliases, a basic part of the SQL language.  They are required in some circumstances but in general make the query easier to write and read.

Comment: ah that makes things much faster/tidier thanks for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

I think INNER JOIN could solve your problem

```
SELECT E.Event, E.Event_Date, R.PlayerName, R.World_Ranking
FROM EVENTS_TABLE E 
INNER JOIN RANKINGS_TABLE R on MONTH(E.Event_Date) = MONTH(R.Ranking_Date)
          AND YEAR(E.Event_Date) = YEAR(R.Ranking_Date)
```